# ALAssetsLibrary: how can I get all the video types from both photo library and video app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, mpmediaquery

my target is to get url of the videos from not just photo library, but also the videos in the video app (all the types including Movies, TV Shows, Music Videos, etc.).

I am using `enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` and I set AlAssetsGroup's filter as allVideos: `[group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];`

I then listed everything in the tableview later.

At the moment I can get all the videos (thumbnail images and url) from the photo library. But I can't get anything from the video app. What should I do?

Many thanks